# Evaluating simple integrals without Barrow's rule

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there a simple way to evaluate integrals of the form

$$
\int_a^bf(x)dx
$$

Without using Barrow's rule?

Simplest example:

$$
\int_2^4xdx
$$

Comment: If you recognize the integral as an area inside a region, then in some special cases you may have a way to find the area without explicitly finding the antiderivative.  For instance, here you have a trapezoid (on its side) with height $2$ and bases $2$ and $4$; you may know that the area is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2 \cdot (2+4) = 6$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want to post that directly in the question, but I was looking for more general answers (besides the geometrical interpretation), I just put that function as an example to see different methods of integrating it.

Answer (score 1):

Before seeing this question, I have never come across the term "Barrow's rule," which seems to be another name for the fundamental theorem of calculus.  Are there other ways to evaluate integrals?  Of course!  For example, some integrals are amenable to a direct analysis from Riemann sums, and others can be evaluated using geometry.  For example, the integral in the question can be converted directly into a question about the area of a particular trapezoid.  Some integrals are solved by adding a parameter, differentiating under the integral sign, and solving a differential equation.  There are many techniques for dealing with integrals of various sorts.  However, most of these techniques rely on the fundamental theorem of calculus at some level, and so while you don't necessarily *have* to use it, most people do for most integrals.